# How to load the required modules only on Drupal site?

Tags: 7

I have a site which contains more than 100 modules. So, for each page every module is getting loaded.

Is there any way to load only required modules to that particular page?

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no such way. Or may be answer is: Yes, it's done automatically. Keep in mind that Drupal loads only the .module file always, and other files (includes, classes, etc) are only loaded when needed. Is true that that 'when needed' may be always for some of the files, but not all.

Answer (score 1):

No need to worry to much about the number of modules loaded since drupal's caching system is quite sophisticated. All nodes are pre-rendered or actually preprocessed – and once you have caching on, your on the safe side.

You should of course (always) ask yourself if using >100 modules is really necessary – or if the same functionalities could also be accomblished by using frewer 'broader' modules – you can for example mimic the functionalities of many tailored modules with the help of a few powerful modules like rules.

So besically *afaik* the number of modules doesn't really affect the processing time or the loading time for the user, at least if caching etc. is activated. But it can become difficult to actually maintain the site – especially when it comes to keeping modules up to date.

Comment: But Drupal is suggesting us to avoid large number of modules modules. https://www.drupal.org/node/1141442

Comment: I was basically refering to the user experience 'guest users' have when caching etc. is turned on. Maintaining a large number of modules can be difficult – and if you can achieve the same functionalities with fewer modules then you should of course go that way.